# Docker app cannot be accessed through opened ports

Tags: docker, networking, flask

I have a flask app inside of a container. I run this container with

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 pyprojects_web
```

It replies

```
 * Serving Flask app "debateit.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

If I run

```
docker container ls
```

I get

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
2221298e6e2c        pyprojects_web      "flask run"         12 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes       0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   elated_joliot
```

If I access http://127.0.0.1:5000 I get:

```
This site can’t be reached
The web page at http://127.0.0.1:5000/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED
```

http://localhost:5000 gives a similar response.

The normal advice is to listen to all connections inside your container with 0.0.0.0 - but I am already doing that. Here is my app:

```
from app import app


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

If I curl from inside of my container it works perfectly:

```
docker exec -it 2221298e6e2c curl http://localhost:5000
```

with a long HTML response, and my server logs get:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2018 01:00:16] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Given these results, and given that I have a "0.0.0.0" host, what is left to try?

Thanks.

Comment: Which operating system are you on? This isn't a flask issue by the way, your setup for flask looks fine.

Comment: What does the following output: `docker run -it --rm --net container:2221298e6e2c nicolaka/netshoot netstat -lnt`

Comment: You probably need to try and access either `192.168.99.100:5000` or `192.168.64.8:5000` depending on which OS.

Comment: @chrisz This is on Ubuntu but I was having a similar problem on Windows using Docker for Windows. My code there isn't my complete Flask app, but to show that I am using 0.0.0.0. I can link my github repo if need be.

Neither of those IPs work for me.

Comment: @BMitch I get 

    Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

Comment: Can you post the full code please? The fact that it says `Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/` when starting is suggesting to me that you're not in fact binding to all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Can you also post your Dockerfile? Want to see how you're starting Flask.

Comment: And the output from the command @BMitch asked you to run confirms that :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So based on the comments it's clear you're not actually running on `0.0.0.0` and that's probably (noticing your `command` for the container) because you're running a newer version of flask where I think you have to pass some args to `flask run`.

Try `flask run --host=0.0.0.0` as the command in your container and I think that will probably work out how you're expecting :)

More info at the [Flask Docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/).

Comment: it really sound like you are right. However, my preliminary testing to prove that hasn't worked. Could you provide me with a little bit more specific details? If I have a line in my Dockerfile with "CMD ["flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]", that should do what you mention, right? This doesn't work for me.

The github repo is at: https://github.com/WarSame/DebateItPy/tree/flask

Comment: I cloned your repo, changed the last instruction to `CMD ["flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]` rebuilt the image and it works great.

Comment: That absolutely works. Thank you very much!

When running it now says "Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)", and hitting localhost:5000 gives me the HTML, which is desired behaviour!

Answer (score 0):

for django project :

`docker exec -it mycontainer bash`

`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

instead of

`python manage.py runserver`

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34364593)